# Collection and Partials in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, collections, partials

This my first time asking a question so please go easy one me :-p

I am following the examples on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials (Section 3.4.5 Rendering Collections) for rendering collections using partials. The code looks simple, but clearly I am missing something.

models/expert.rb contains the line:

```
attr_accessible :name
```

experts_controller.rb contains the following line in the index method:

```
@experts = Expert.all
```

views/experts/index.html.erb contains the following line:

```
<%= render :partial => "expert", :collection => @experts %>
```

views/experts/_expert.html.erb contains:

```
<%= expert.name %>
```

Upon viewing the index page in my browser I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Experts#index
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

I have been working on this for an hour and am completely stumped :-/ What little thing am I missing?

---**Clarification**---

Running '<%= debug @experts %>' within index.html.erb produces the following output:

```
- !ruby/object:Expert
attributes:
    id: 1
    name: Bob Smith
    slug: bob-smith
    created_at: '2012-03-11 18:37:11.791118'
    updated_at: '2012-03-11 18:55:58.179629'
  changed_attributes: {}
  previously_changed: {}
  attributes_cache: {}
  marked_for_destruction: false
  destroyed: false
  readonly: false
  new_record: false
- !ruby/object:Expert
  attributes:
    id: 2
    name: Steve Kamp
    slug: steve-kamp
    created_at: !!null 
    updated_at: !!null 
  changed_attributes: {}
  previously_changed: {}
  attributes_cache: {}
  marked_for_destruction: false
  destroyed: false
  readonly: false
  new_record: false
```

Comment: Does your Expert model actually have a `name` field? `attr_accessible` allows it to be assigned through mass assignment, but you must create the field in the schema (typically using a migration) in order for it to exist.

Comment: @Jeremy Roman: Undefined method for nil class means he called #name on Nil. If `@expert` was not nil but there was no name attribute he would get `NoMethodError`

Comment: Welcome to SO, good first question BTW.

Comment: Oh, I missed that it was on `nil`. My mind saw `Expert` again. (But it's `NoMethodError` in both cases.)

Comment: @DannyDover: Ok, your error screen should show you a line number that the error is occuring on, can you paste the area around that line? Or, better yet, paste in the entire file where the error is occurring.

Comment: The code you've pasted looks absolutely correct to me, so I'd guess that there is some other code in `ExpertsController#index` that is trying to call `name` on `nil`.

Could you possibly give us the full code of at that method?

Comment: @Andrew and Jeremy, you two were right. The problem was that I was calling the partial later on in the code on index.html.erb. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception almost certainly means that there are no experts, so `@experts` is an empty array. Have you created any expert records yet?

Also, just so you'll know, to render a collection of objects the way you're doing there's a nice shortcut:

```
render @experts
```

Comment: `Expert.all` returns `[]`, not `nil`, when there are no records. `:collection` then does iteration, which would raise an error if it were `nil` (rather than the attempted invocation of `name`).

Comment: I believe I have two records. `<%= debug expert %>` returns: `--- !ruby/object:Expert
attributes:
  id: 1
  name: Steve Smith`... and a different group of attributes for the second instance of the partial that is rendered

Comment: That did the trick! The issue was that there was another instance of the partial being called in index.html.erb that didn't include the collection, this @experts was undefined for the second instance.